# Creating a custom metric for Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have embedded the Google Analytics API to my website (developed using php, yii2 framework). I would like to create a custom metric to include in my chart. The value for my custom metric would be from my database. From the documentation, I tried using the following snippet:

```
var metric1Value = <?= $modelValue; ?>
ga('set', 'metric1', metric1Value);
```

This however results in an error stating that 'ga' is undefined. Is it even possible to create a custom metric in Google Analytics? If it is, how can it be achieved?

Here's an overview of my code if it helps. I've followed the [tutorial](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Analytics Test</div>
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="date-range-selector-container"></div>
<div id="table-container" style="margin:5%"></div>

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {       
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: 'myclientid'
    });

    var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            'start-date':'50daysAgo',
            'end-date':'yesterday',
            'metrics': [['ga:sessions', 'ga:users', 'ga:newUsers', 'ga:pageviews']],
            'dimensions': [['ga:date']],
        },
        chart: {
            container: 'table-container',
            type: 'TABLE',
            options: {
                width: '80%'
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see that you have included the analytics.js library which defines the ga object.

Comment: I was in the wrong assumption that the analytics.js was referenced in the first javascript function. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Syntax you're using is for tracking custom metric on your website, and code you're using is for showing report data. If you want to show custom metric then add  `ga:metric1` in your metric list

e.g.
`'metrics': [['ga:sessions', 'ga:users', 'ga:newUsers', 'ga:pageviews']]`
will be
`'metrics': [['ga:sessions', 'ga:users', 'ga:newUsers', 'ga:pageviews', 'ga:metric1']]`

Note: Your metric needs to be configured in Google Analytics Account Panel

Comment: Thanks. But how can I set the value for the custom metric in the panel?

Comment: Custom metric value needs to be collected on pages where analytics is implemented.

Say you have a page http://example.com/page-a.html and there you add `custom metric 1` before page view call or event call. it will start reporting to your google analytics reports and from those reports you can display in your report queries.

makes sense?